# preタグのなかにある数値を四角の囲み数値にしたい

Tags: html

preタグのなかに数値の羅列があって、そのいくつかを四角の囲み数値にしたいのですが、borderなどCSSを当てられないので困っています。

何とか表現できないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

preタグの中でも、タグは解釈されます。
そのため囲み数値にしたい部分をタグで囲ってから、そこにCSSを当てるとよいでしょう。
サンプルとしては以下のようなものになります

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <pre>
    test
    <span style="border: 1px solid">test2</span>
  </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: preタグはhtmlもテキストとして認識させるタグと思ったのですがcodeがそうだったんですかね？

Comment: いいえ。そう言った効果はどちらのタグにもありませんので、表示上はエスケープする必要があります。preタグは整形済みテキストとしてスペースや改行、タブを無視せず表示するようにするもので、codeタグはソースコードですよ、というのを示すタグです。

Comment: スペースや改行、タブを無視せず表示するだけで、他はpタグなどと変わらないのですね。ありがとうございます。